# SharePoint Online - Granular Document Permissions for 20 Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, item-level-permissions

I am creating a technical documentation wiki which includes documents.

At present I have one Document library. The problem I'm trying to solve is permissions.

Each set of document needs to have different permissions. There are around 1,000 documents and 20 teams, so for example;

- Document 1 can be viewed by Team 1 and Team 2 but not any other teams
- Document 2 can be viewed by Team 1 and Team 7 but not any other teams
- Document 3 can be viewed by Team 4 and Team 7 but not any other teams
- Document 4 can be viewed by Team 3, Team 7 and Team 9
- Document 5 can be viewed by Team 3, Team 7 and Team 9

What's the best way to manage this? My only thoughts so far are to either different document libraries or folders but I would need lots of folders. It needs to be simple for the users to change the permissions and see what permissions a document or set of documents has.

Eg

- Team 1 and Team 2 Read
- Team 1 and Team 3 Read
- Team 1 and Team 4 Read...

Any advice?

Comment: Are these documents confidential that other team shouldn't see?  I am think of target audience here.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Yes they are confidential from a security point of view, my understanding of target audiences is that if the user has the document URL they can still access, it just makes it harder for them to find, is that correct?

Comment: If it is confidential target audience is not ideal. I would go with document library for each team and with modern library you can leave links behind for other libraries

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look into that. I might force a public and private folder or library for each team to make things simpler.

Comment: I had a similar situation last week. One thing I did is not to create libraries based on teams but rather functions I.e. projects, operations, IT etc because team composition will change but functional area will not.  Just a thought.

Comment: That is a good idea, makes it a bit more robust :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Sharepointer, the best design is a number of libraries, each with separate permissions. In order to make it user friendly you could create a search based  common library overview page inc most recent updates

That will also cover the "highly" unusual scenario where the requirements changes and other team needs access to one of the libraries :-)

Answer (score 1):

We have similar situation in our organization. Our procedure to handle this is to create an active directory or SharePoint group for each logical/functional group who will have access to a unique set of documents. We create libraries with granular permissions(unique permissions) for folders corresponding to each logical/functional group. We can keep adding and deleting particular users to these groups whenever an individual needs access to the documents.